# Where is it best advised to include JavaScript and CSS files in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Where is it best advised to include JavaScript and CSS files, in the case you have a theme and a sub-theme? Does it have the same effect when you use those files from a .info file, a template file, or a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JavaScript files, the files are being grouped by where they are called from. Below is the order in which they are called.

1. Libraries: Libraries, settings, or jQuery plugins
2. Modules: Javascript files added by modules
3. Themes: Javascript files added by theme (like in `.info` files)

See the description for `$options` given in [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

For CSS files, there are three groups too.

1. System layer CSS files (e.g. modules/system/system.menus.css and modules/system/system.theme.css)
2. CSS files added by modules
3. CSS files added by themes

See the description for `$options` in [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7).

Comment: tanx for the useful info @Muhammad Reda.but i would like to know if there is any difference in action when adding the javascript and css files in .info,.module,template files...

Comment: The only difference will be due to the **order of execution**, which is illustrated above.